# vue3 + vite で named exportエラー

Tags: vue.js

#### 実現したいこと

Vite + Vue3でmoduleのimportを適切に処理できるようにしたい。

#### 前提

Vite + Vue3 + （Amplify）で、main.ts内で、以下のように定義したところ、named exportエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import { Project } from '@/API';

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure({
    ...awsExports,
});

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/API.ts?t=1682717823643' does not provide an export named 'Project'
```

#### 試したこと

- tsconfig.jsonにtargetとmoduleでesnextを設定
- tsconfig.jsonにtype: moduleを設定
- API.tsを絶対パスしてい等で設定する（Aliasの問題の可能性）

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

mswでmock情報をgraphql-codegenを使って、mockデータを自動生成して、handler定義をしようとしており、mockデータが型定義を読み込む場合に同じエラーが発生しており、試行錯誤の上で、一旦この問題にたどり着きました。vite + vue3でHelloWorldなどのcomponentからは上記の@/APIの定義で同様の方法で問題なく動作しています。

ES module絡みだと思ってはいるのと、app.mount後とその前でmoduleのインポートの動作が変わっているような気はしているのですが、具体的な対応方法が検討がつかない状況です。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/599cmk5l3lkzrx